# Fabric Js - Canvas Side

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am developing the functionality that is similar to given below link.
http://printio.ru/classic_tees/new

But i am unable to find the way to implement this functionality . Can any one guide me through ?
[image]

Comment: The link you provided is broken...

Comment: @Blindman67 I have updated that link